# Errors when installing and using mysql-python in OS X 10.9.4

Tags: python, mysql, macos

I use pip to install MySQLdb module in my computer:

```
sudo pip install mysql-python
```

Here is the information when installing:

```
Downloading/unpacking mysql-python
Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB): 108kB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/mysql-python/setup.py) egg_info for package mysql-python

Installing collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py install for mysql-python
building '_mysql' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:348:11: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined
  #define SIZEOF_SIZE_T  SIZEOF_LONG
          ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:43:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           8
                ^
In file included from _mysql.c:44:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:442:9: warning: 'HAVE_WCSCOLL' macro redefined
#define HAVE_WCSCOLL
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:906:9: note: previous definition is here
#define HAVE_WCSCOLL 1
        ^
_mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                         ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                               ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1127:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1129:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1168:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
#define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
#define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1178:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1180:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1274:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
#define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                        ^
_mysql.c:1466:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1468:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                        len = strlen(buf);
                            ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1504:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1506:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                len = strlen(buf);
                                    ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
_mysql.c:1589:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
        if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
            ~~~ ^ ~
16 warnings generated.
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient_r -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.so -arch x86_64

Successfully installed mysql-python
Cleaning up...
```

and then I write a program to connect to my MySQL database:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "", "test")
```

but the program crashed with information as below:

```
Process:         Python [7300]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.5 (2.7.5)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  zsh [459]
Responsible:     Terminal [453]
User ID:         501

PlugIn Path:       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
PlugIn Identifier: _mysql.so
PlugIn Version:    ??? (0)

Date/Time:       2014-09-19 15:22:55.084 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  68F0B263-8B42-D1E3-1E1A-FFC816C3A9A3


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007faa00000001

VM Regions Near 0x7faa00000001:
    VM_ALLOCATE            0000000105dda000-0000000105ddb000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=ALI  
--> 
    MALLOC_TINY            00007faa00c00000-00007faa00d00000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x000000010583ac3e cli_advanced_command + 286
1   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x000000010583f197 mysql_real_query + 60
2   libmysqlclient.18.dylib         0x0000000105838e29 mysql_autocommit + 36
3   _mysql.so                       0x0000000105826163 _mysql_ConnectionObject_autocommit + 64
4   org.python.python               0x000000010556bf72 PyObject_Call + 101
5   org.python.python               0x00000001055e801f PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
6   org.python.python               0x000000010557d1b6 0x105562000 + 111030
7   org.python.python               0x000000010556bf72 PyObject_Call + 101
8   org.python.python               0x00000001055e5df5 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 15416
9   org.python.python               0x00000001055e8864 0x105562000 + 551012
10  org.python.python               0x00000001055e54d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
11  org.python.python               0x00000001055e2093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
12  org.python.python               0x0000000105589796 0x105562000 + 161686
13  org.python.python               0x000000010556bf72 PyObject_Call + 101
14  org.python.python               0x00000001055769a7 0x105562000 + 84391
15  org.python.python               0x000000010556bf72 PyObject_Call + 101
16  org.python.python               0x00000001055b16ce 0x105562000 + 325326
17  org.python.python               0x00000001055ad184 0x105562000 + 307588
18  org.python.python               0x000000010556bf72 PyObject_Call + 101
19  org.python.python               0x00000001055e6395 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16856
20  org.python.python               0x00000001055e2093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
21  org.python.python               0x00000001055e88c8 0x105562000 + 551112
22  org.python.python               0x00000001055e54d4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13079
23  org.python.python               0x00000001055e2093 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1641
24  org.python.python               0x00000001055e1a24 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
25  org.python.python               0x0000000105600c2c 0x105562000 + 650284
26  org.python.python               0x0000000105600cd3 PyRun_FileExFlags + 137
27  org.python.python               0x0000000105600821 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718
28  org.python.python               0x0000000105611363 Py_Main + 2995
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9786a5fd start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007faa00000001  rbx: 0x00007faa0103ee30  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007faa0103ee30  rsi: 0x0000000000000001  rbp: 0x00007fff5a6a69e0  rsp: 0x00007fff5a6a68a0
   r8: 0x0000000000000006   r9: 0x0000000000000010  r10: 0x0000000105b2b108  r11: 0x00007fa8fb79aaf2
  r12: 0x0000000105d67710  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000010
  rip: 0x000000010583ac3e  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x00007faa00000001

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x105558000 -        0x105558fff  org.python.python (2.7.5 - 2.7.5) <6408A335-53CA-3F47-9122-CE9278A9A269> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x105562000 -        0x10564cfff  org.python.python (2.7.5 - 2.7.5) <8DD65C8B-686D-3BF1-8682-70F02D28D200> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x1056e0000 -        0x1056effff  libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib (61) <F5827491-A4E3-3471-A540-8D1FE241FD99> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libSimplifiedChineseConverter.dylib
       0x105823000 -        0x105827fff +_mysql.so (0) <13FC59D6-7820-3DD4-88DE-D30642620BA9> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
       0x105833000 -        0x105b29fff  libmysqlclient.18.dylib (18) <EE0331DB-585F-34F3-8AE7-E01C4E1D0824> /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
       0x105c4a000 -        0x105c4dff7  math.so (76.100.1) <415E6D75-85F7-3D95-9905-040F841DC01C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x105c53000 -        0x105c54fff  time.so (76.100.1) <3F39C81C-ED55-3D6B-8EB6-BB639C229500> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x105c5a000 -        0x105c63fff  datetime.so (76.100.1) <B14EFA6A-31B0-3915-847B-F78F46785BD2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x105cac000 -        0x105caffff  strop.so (76.100.1) <7DF9F1F3-B787-3012-9777-96764E72F686> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x105cb5000 -        0x105cb9fff  array.so (76.100.1) <68E3E29C-5A8D-3F9A-B80F-A44D01FDD394> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so
       0x105d2c000 -        0x105d2efff  _collections.so (76.100.1) <37AE71A4-75D6-3FAD-80B3-D9AAB3345CDF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x105d34000 -        0x105d37fff  operator.so (76.100.1) <682B1D94-E453-32DC-A90B-8A562B8EE727> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x105d7d000 -        0x105d81fff  itertools.so (76.100.1) <B7032D75-A18E-3F87-8041-CE6C1017229E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x105d8a000 -        0x105d8bfff  _heapq.so (76.100.1) <734C85F3-F3FB-39E6-A654-84107FFE31AD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x105dd0000 -        0x105dd1fff  _functools.so (76.100.1) <90D6FCF9-9CDB-346C-AC33-6A9B432DF895> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x105dd5000 -        0x105dd6fff  _locale.so (76.100.1) <FBD74B95-5CB4-3FA8-9678-4F6B701B901A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
    0x7fff6608e000 -     0x7fff660c1817  dyld (239.4) <042C4CED-6FB2-3B1C-948B-CAF2EE3B9F7A> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8daf1000 -     0x7fff8daf2ffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8e413000 -     0x7fff8e42dfff  libdispatch.dylib (339.92.1) <C4E4A18D-3C3B-3C9C-8709-A4270D998DE7> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8e5ac000 -     0x7fff8e5faff9  libstdc++.6.dylib (60) <0241E6A4-1368-33BE-950B-D0A175C41F54> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff8e6a8000 -     0x7fff8e6aaff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.15) <4998CB6A-9D54-390A-9F57-5D1AC53C135C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8e6b5000 -     0x7fff8e6b9ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8e97c000 -     0x7fff8e981fff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff8ea04000 -     0x7fff8ea05ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8f6e1000 -     0x7fff8f6e8fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8f867000 -     0x7fff8f86effb  libcopyfile.dylib (103.92.1) <CF29DFF6-0589-3590-834C-82E2316612E8> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8fdef000 -     0x7fff8fdf3ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.90.3) <4E51D5B0-92A0-3D0D-B90E-495A1ED3E391> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8ff5c000 -     0x7fff8ff66fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff904ee000 -     0x7fff90530ff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff907df000 -     0x7fff907f0ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff907f1000 -     0x7fff90815fff  libxpc.dylib (300.90.2) <AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff91103000 -     0x7fff9112aff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff91897000 -     0x7fff918e9fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff918ea000 -     0x7fff91938fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff91edf000 -     0x7fff91f08ff7  libc++abi.dylib (49.1) <21A807D3-6732-3455-B77F-743E9F916DF0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff926a2000 -     0x7fff926a9ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff941f2000 -     0x7fff9439ff27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff944fa000 -     0x7fff944fbff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <E303F2F8-A8CF-3DF3-84B3-F2D0EE41CCF6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff9451e000 -     0x7fff9453aff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.110.17) <873931CE-D1AF-3596-AADB-D2E63C9AB29F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff949a4000 -     0x7fff94b89fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.17) <729BD6DA-1F63-3E72-A148-26F21EBF52BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff95d9f000 -     0x7fff95da5ff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.90.1) <3C3D3DA8-32B9-3243-98EC-D89B9A1670B3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff960cb000 -     0x7fff960cdff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff96fd0000 -     0x7fff96fd8fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.92.1) <17B03FFD-92C5-3282-9981-EBB28B456207> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff97863000 -     0x7fff97864ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff97867000 -     0x7fff9786aff7  libdyld.dylib (239.4) <7C9EC3B7-DDE3-33FF-953F-4067C743951D> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff97946000 -     0x7fff97947fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11.1) <0D0B13EA-6B7A-3AC8-BE60-B548543BEB77> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff98a57000 -     0x7fff98a5eff8  liblaunch.dylib (842.92.1) <A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff98e3b000 -     0x7fff98e44ff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <52571EC3-6894-37E4-946E-064B021ED44E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff99f60000 -     0x7fff9a118ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (511.34) <616A65D6-3F20-3EAB-8CA8-273AD890261C> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff9a119000 -     0x7fff9a134ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff9a57e000 -     0x7fff9a607ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.90.3) <6FD3A400-4BB2-3B95-B90C-BE6E9D0D78FA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff9a608000 -     0x7fff9a608ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff9ad45000 -     0x7fff9ad4aff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff9ad59000 -     0x7fff9ad5afff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff9ad5b000 -     0x7fff9ad8afd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff9af2c000 -     0x7fff9af53ffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff9af7d000 -     0x7fff9af8eff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 628
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=80.2M resident=20.7M(26%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=59.5M(74%)
Writable regions: Total=31.0M written=3596K(11%) resident=4528K(14%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=26.5M(86%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             22.5M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                          12K
__DATA                             2012K
__LINKEDIT                         67.1M
__TEXT                             13.1M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             169.3M

Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B12, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f9
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (6.30.223.154.65)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.6f1 14216, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

What's the problem? Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Not a real answer, but: I have ended up using the [myssql.connector](http://geert.vanderkelen.org/installing-coy-using-pip/) instead of MySQLdb. It appears to be working more reliably.